# How do i check html binding before create directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, custom-directive

A page, i called custom select-box directive to show Month and that directive need some arguments:

```
<custom-select-box
     id="month"
     model="month"
     model-required
     model-name="month"
     options="month.value as month.name for month in months"
     aria-label="{{month.name}}">
     <option value="">{{'dcl-spa.components.claim-and-link.month.mm'|translate}}</option>
</custom-select-box>
```

But when i direct to this page or refresh, the argument `{{'dcl-spa.components.claim-and-link.month.mm'|translate}}` in `<option>` can not bind to html, just show the key `dcl-spa.components.claim-and-link.month.mm` on page.
The directive custom-select-box can not be change.
So what should i do on this case? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The option markup should be inside the `custom-select-box directive template.`

Comment: That's directive can not change,

Comment: You're not giving much information - where is this directive coming from?